# Same form of dataset has 2 different shapes

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, training-data

I am quite new to Machine Learning and am just grasping the techniques. As such, I am trying to train a model on the following classifiers using a dataset that has 4 features and the target feature/class (the truth value *1* or *0*).

**Classifiers**

- SGD Classifier
- Random Forest Classifier
- Linear Support Vector Classifier
- Gaussian Process Classifier

I am training the model on the following dataset [Part of the dataset is shown below].

**Training set : train_sop_truth.csv**

```
Subject,Predicate,Object,Computed,Truth
concept:sportsteam:hawks,concept:teamplaysincity,concept:city:atlanta,0.4255912602,1
concept:stadiumoreventvenue:honda+AF8-center,concept:stadiumlocatedincity,concept:city:anaheim,0.4276425838,1
concept:sportsteam:ducks,concept:teamplaysincity,concept:city:anaheim,0.4762486517,1
concept:sportsteam:n1985+AF8-chicago+AF8-bears,concept:teamplaysincity,concept:city:chicago,0.4106097221,1
concept:stadiumoreventvenue:philips+AF8-arena,concept:stadiumlocatedincity,concept:city:atlanta,0.4190083146,1
concept:stadiumoreventvenue:united+AF8-center,concept:stadiumlocatedincity,concept:city:chicago,0.4211134315,1
```

The test dataset is in another .csv file as `test_sop_truth.csv`.

**Testing set : test_sop_truth.csv**

```
Subject,Predicate,Object,Computed,Truth
Nigel_Cole,isMarriedTo,Kate_Isitt,0.9350595474,1
Véra_Clouzot,isMarriedTo,Henri-Georges_Clouzot,0.4773990512,1
Norodom_Sihanouk,produced,The_Last_Days_of_Colonel_Savath,0.3942225575,1
Farouk_of_Egypt,isMarriedTo,Farida_of_Egypt,0.4276426733,1
```

Then I wanted to check the shape of the features for each and expected to see the same number of features as I am applying the same transformations to both datasets. But they differed.

**Python Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from termcolor import colored

features = pd.read_csv('../Data/train_sop_truth.csv')
testFeatures = pd.read_csv('../Data/test_sop_truth.csv')
print(features.head(5))

print(colored('\nThe shape of our features is:','green'), features.shape)
print(colored('\nThe shape of our Test features is:','green'), testFeatures.shape)

print()
print(colored('\n     DESCRIPTIVE STATISTICS\n','yellow'))
print(colored(features.describe(),'cyan'))
print()
print(colored(testFeatures.describe(),'cyan'))


features = pd.get_dummies(features)
testFeatures = pd.get_dummies(testFeatures)

features.iloc[:,5:].head(5)
testFeatures.iloc[:,5].head(5)

labels = np.array(features['Truth'])
testlabels = np.array(testFeatures['Truth'])


features= features.drop('Truth', axis = 1)
testFeatures = testFeatures.drop('Truth', axis = 1)

feature_list = list(features.columns)
testFeature_list = list(testFeatures.columns)

features = np.array(features)
testFeatures = np.array(testFeatures)

train_samples = 100


testX_train, textX_test, testy_train, testy_test = model_selection.train_test_split(testFeatures, testlabels, test_size=0.25, random_state = 42)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)

print(colored('\n    TRAINING & TESTING SETS','yellow'))
print(colored('\nTraining Features Shape:','magenta'), X_train.shape)
print(colored('Training Labels Shape:','magenta'), X_test.shape)
print(colored('Testing Features Shape:','magenta'), y_train.shape)
print(colored('Testing Labels Shape:','magenta'), y_test.shape)

print()

print(colored('\n    TRAINING & TESTING SETS','yellow'))
print(colored('\nTraining Features Shape:','magenta'), testX_train.shape)
print(colored('Training Labels Shape:','magenta'), textX_test.shape)
print(colored('Testing Features Shape:','magenta'), testy_train.shape)
print(colored('Testing Labels Shape:','magenta'), testy_test.shape)
```

**Output**

```
The shape of our features is: (1860, 5)

The shape of our Test features is: (1386, 5)


     DESCRIPTIVE STATISTICS

          Computed        Truth
count  1860.000000  1860.000000
mean      0.443222     0.913441
std       0.110788     0.281264
min       0.000000     0.000000
25%       0.418164     1.000000
50%       0.427643     1.000000
75%       0.450023     1.000000
max       1.000000     1.000000

          Computed        Truth
count  1386.000000  1386.000000
mean      0.511809     0.992063
std       0.197954     0.088765
min       0.009042     0.000000
25%       0.418649     1.000000
50%       0.429140     1.000000
75%       0.515809     1.000000
max       1.702856     1.000000

    TRAINING & TESTING SETS

Training Features Shape: (1395, 1045)
Training Labels Shape: (465, 1045)
Testing Features Shape: (1395,)
Testing Labels Shape: (465,)


    TRAINING & TESTING SETS

Training Features Shape: (1039, 1790)
Training Labels Shape: (347, 1790)
Testing Features Shape: (1039,)
Testing Labels Shape: (347,)
```

What I do not understand here is how the feature shape can be different as `1045` for the features(training set) and `1790` for the testFeatures (testing set), despite undergoing the same transformations and having the same number of features and form of features in the csv files.

Any suggestions or clarifications in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is with calling pd.get_dummies, this will add all the category to a column, and when your training and test feature have different values of category, this will result in different number of columns.

Comment: If I may ask, why your training and testing data is soo different? as in format of the values is also different.

Comment: @Sach, One dataset is driven from NELL facts that is in the form of the training set and the other is driven from Yago. But the idea of both adheres to the same concept of being the subject, object and predicate.

Comment: @Sach When you say **different values of category**, isn't it still considered as simple string with categorical values as opposed to the `Computed` feature, which is the only continuous values feature and lies within the range of 1 and 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you apply get_dummies for the test dataset you might have got few columns added or deleted based on the data values of the categorical variables.

```
def add_missing_dummy_columns( d, columns ):
        missing_cols = set( columns ) - set( d.columns )
        for c in missing_cols:
            d[c] = 0

def fix_columns( d, columns ):  

    add_missing_dummy_columns( d, columns )

    # make sure we have all the columns we need
    assert( set( columns ) - set( d.columns ) == set())

    extra_cols = set( d.columns ) - set( columns )
    if extra_cols: print ("extra columns:", extra_cols)

    d = d[ columns ]
    return d

testFeatures= fix_columns( testFeatures, features.columns )
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my issue with the inconsistent column numbers.